# How to tell Swagger V3 that my "Java Date" is just a "date", not a "datetime"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have this annotated (Spring-Boot, REST-Service, swagger-annotations-2.1.2) Java code:

```
@JsonProperty("InitialAbrechMonat")
@Schema(name = "InitialAbrechMonat", description = "blabla", format = "date",
        pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", example = "2020-12-01")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
public Date getInitialAbrechMonat() {
```

Not sure if *format = "date"* in @Schema does anything, but I've seen a *format = "date-time"* somewhere, so I tried. Anyway, Swagger both ignores my "example", "pattern" and "format" and shows me this:

```
"InitialAbrechMonat": "2021-02-25T13:50:35.705Z",
```

In the "Example Value | Schema" section of the generated web documentation/UI.

I want to see either the example I actually gave, or at least a date formatted as "yyyy-MM-dd", so as not to confuse my users.

EDIT: I added "pattern" and "format" only *after* seeing it ignored my "example".

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalDate` instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @daniu That would solve my problem, but that's kind of a work-around, rather than the solution I'm looking for. I *could have* code that expected "getInitialAbrechMonat()" to return a Date, given our code-base is 20+ years old...

Comment: Swagger or not, I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). This also means that I disagree that it’s a workaround. It’s an upgrade that you would want anyway.

Comment: Well, using LocalDate doesn't even work out-of-the-box: " org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2021-02-01')"

Answer (score 0):

```
@Schema(type = "string", format = "date")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider going through Stack Overflow's help section in order to know how to answer a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Artem, when 'format' is specified, 'type' is getting ignored and also example. And date is shown in swagger UI as mentioned by Sebastien in question. Check my answer which works for users as well as purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It can be configured as below as well mentioning required format in description which would help API users to understand better.

```
@JsonFormat (pattern = "ddMMyy")    
@Schema (type = "string", example = "010123", description = "Date in format ddMMyy")
Date sampleDate;
```

Swagger schema will show something like below

```
sampleDate  string
            example: 010123
            Date in format ddMMyy
```